# Import content into excel sheet

Tags: c#, php, sql

I came up with some code back in the day that allowed me to download a PDF file onto my desktop. It was written in C#.

I am somewhat trying to do the same thing but in PHP. I was wondering if anyone had any samples of what I am trying to do.

I'm not sure if it can be done within MS Word. I have done something similar with Excel.

I am trying to take a Excel file and grab content off of multiple websites.

The websites generates new query's simultaneously every half hour or so.

I want to be able to retrieve the content and import the content into a excel file so I can try to rearrange information. Read the content off of 3 to 4 websites and download it into the excel file to possibly organize the content with tables.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string url = "http://www.uakron.edu/dotAsset/1265971.pdf", localPath = "1265971.pdf";

        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate");
        if(File.Exists(localPath))
            req.IfModifiedSince = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(localPath);
        try
        {
            using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
            {
                int len;
                checked
                {
                    len = (int)resp.ContentLength;
                }
                using (var file = File.Create(localPath))
                using (var data = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while (len > 0 && (bytesRead = data.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(len, buffer.Length))) > 0)
                    {
                        len -= bytesRead;
                        file.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("New version downloaded");
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Response == null || ex.Status != WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                throw;
            Console.WriteLine("Not updated");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to develop an app that has a timing interval so it can allow me to determine how many minutes I can generate the new query's into the file. I'm trying to generate the code in php in a inline styling format. All one script. Instead of C# where it takes multiple files.

It's for a job website I created. 
(I'm not trying to steal content.)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would make some http request directly from excel to your websites (eg. in csv format). Then you can use the information the way you want (and use a timestamp to know wich data to update).

Here is an example of http get request in excel: http://ubuntujourney.blogspot.fr/2011/04/getting-web-request-with-get-request-in.html